# Cannot extract Azure Sql Server database after enabling database auditing and threat detection

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, sqlpackage, securitycenter

After enabling auditing and threat detection in Azure for my Sql Server database, I can no longer extract my database dacpac using sqlPackage.exe as I'm presented with this error:

```
The element ##MS_DatabaseMasterKey## is not supported in Microsoft Azure SQL Database v12.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news! That's been fixed in newer versions of SqlPackage.exe.  You can download the latest version of SqlPackage.exe here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54106

Note that this version installs SqlPackage under the **130** folder in Microsoft Sql Server, where earlier versions might be found in the 120 or 110 folder.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply but updating to the latest version of sqlPackage resolved my error. Thanks!